# SSL Handshake with Cloud Code HTTP Request

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to see if it's possible to do an SSL handshake through cloud code. So far all I have found is https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-certificate-to-httprequest

But I was hoping to get a more clear answer regarding whether this is possible or not.

Comment: What about the link don't you understand ?

Comment: it looks like the person who started the thread was unable to get it to work with the tls connection options.

he ended up having to spin up another server to ping for the api call, my question is regarding whether this is still necessary. is there a way to do an http request with ssl handshake without spinning up another server?